# React navigation loses params on navigating back with key

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm in a situation that user needs to navigate for a moment to group of other screens to add some data and then go back to the first screen.
The first screen has data that was passed to it through navigate params. I need this data to remain after changing screens.
This works when user in order to get back there is using couple times

```
navigation.goBack()
```

but when I try to go back to specific screen using

```
navigation.navigate({key: 'edit'})
```

then it pops

```
Render error
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_route$params.payment')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [popToTop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#poptotop) or [pop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#pop) to go back multiple screens.

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());

// or

navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(2));
```